# Why are these Gradient Accumulation implementations not working?

Tags: tensorflow

> #### Note:
>
> After experimenting I noticed that this problem only occurs when I am training on the GPU. I created a github issue ([#50454](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/50454)). At this point I am not sure what is happening exactly.

I am working on an implementation for Gradient Accumulation. However, none of the approaches seem to work. Below I am describing two approaches which could work theoretically but it appears to conflict with Tensorflow.

#### The idea

I want to patch an arbitrary `Optimizer`-instance by replacing its `apply_gradients()` function by my own implementation which accumulates gradients.

```py
# Build model first
model.build()

# Patch the optimizer
optimizer = get_patched_optimizer(optimizer, n, model.trainable_variables)

# Compile the model with the patched optimizer
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer)
```

where

```py
def get_patched_optimizer(optimizer, n, trainable_variables):
    """Patch optimizer for gradient accumulation.

    :param optimizer:
        The optimizer to patch.
    :param n:
        The number of accumulation steps before applying gradients.
    :param trainable_variables:
        Trainable parameters of the model
    :return:
        A patched patched optimizer for gradient accumulation.
    """
    accumulator = _GradientAccumulationPatch(
        n=n,
        orig_apply_gradients=optimizer.apply_gradients,
        trainable_variables=trainable_variables
    )

    # Replace the original function
    optimizer.apply_gradients = accumulator.apply_gradients

    return optimizer
```

### The happy (but not working) path

The simplest way would be to just accumulate gradients and apply gradients conditionally e.g. whenever `current_step % n == 0`.

However, the problem here is that it looks like I am not able to use `tf.cond()` in this context in contrast to how they're doing it in [Gradient Accumulation with Custom model.fit in TF.Keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66472201/gradient-accumulation-with-custom-model-fit-in-tf-keras).

Using `tf.cond()` results in the following `RuntimeError`

> RuntimeError: `merge_call` called while defining a new graph or a tf.function. This can often happen if the function `fn` passed to `strategy.run()` contains a nested `@tf.function`, and the nested `@tf.function` contains a synchronization point, such as aggregating gradients (e.g, optimizer.apply_gradients), or if the function `fn` uses a control flow statement which contains a synchronization point in the body. Such behaviors are not yet supported. Instead, please avoid nested `tf.function`s or control flow statements that may potentially cross a synchronization boundary, for example, wrap the `fn` passed to `strategy.run` or the entire `strategy.run` inside a `tf.function` or move the control flow out of `fn`

Here is the implementation of `_GradientAccumulationPatch` using `tf.cond()`:

```py
class _GradientAccumulationPatch:

    def __init__(
        self,
        n: int,
        orig_apply_gradients,
        trainable_variables
    ):
        self.n = tf.constant(n, dtype=tf.int64)
        policy = tf.keras.mixed_precision.global_policy()
        self.variable_dtype = policy.variable_dtype
        self.accu_gradients = [
            tf.Variable(
                tf.zeros(g.shape, dtype=g.dtype),
            ) for g in trainable_variables
        ]

        self._current_step = tf.Variable(0, dtype=tf.int64)
        self._orig_apply_gradients = orig_apply_gradients

    def apply_gradients(self, grads_and_vars, *args, **kwargs):

        trainable_variables = [var for (_, var) in grads_and_vars]
        gradients = [grad for (grad, _) in grads_and_vars]

        # Always accumulate gradients
        for i, grad in enumerate(gradients):
            self.accu_gradients[i].assign_add(grad)

        tf.cond(
            self._can_apply_on_next_step(),
            true_fn=lambda: self.apply_accu_gradients(trainable_variables, args, kwargs),
            false_fn=lambda: None
        )

    def apply_accu_gradients(self, trainable_variables, *args, **kwargs):

        # Call the original apply_gradients() function
        self._orig_apply_gradients(zip(self.accu_gradients, trainable_variables), *args, **kwargs)

        # Reset all accumulated gradients to zero
        for i in range(len(self.accu_gradients)):
            self.accu_gradients[i].assign(tf.zeros_like(trainable_variables[i]))

    def _can_apply_on_next_step(self):
        """
        :return: True if gradients should be applied; False otherwise.
        """
        # Increment (always do this first)
        self._current_step.assign_add(1)
        count_mod_steps = tf.math.mod(self._current_step, self.n)
        return tf.equal(count_mod_steps, 0)
```

### The more complicated path (also not working)

It is possible to remove the `tf.cond()` by simply using the signal `apply`, given by `_can_apply_on_next_step()`, as a multiplication factor and apply zero-gradients whenever we are in the accumulation-phase.

The idea would be to always accumulate gradients and always apply them with one particular change:

```py
final_gradients = [grad * apply for grad in gradients]
self._orig_apply_gradients(zip(final_gradients, trainable_variables))
```

This is how we'd change the `apply_gradients()` method:

```py
def apply_gradients(self, grads_and_vars, *args, **kwargs):

    can_apply = self._can_apply_on_next_step()
    # 1.0 whenever we want to apply gradients; 0.0 otherwise
    apply = tf.cast(can_apply, dtype=self.variable_dtype)
    # Will be 0.0 if apply is 1.0 and vice versa
    keep = tf.cast(tf.logical_not(can_apply), dtype=self.variable_dtype)

    grads_and_vars = list(grads_and_vars)
    gradients = [grad for (grad, _) in grads_and_vars]
    trainable_variables = [var for (_, var) in grads_and_vars]

    # Accumulate gradients
    for i, grad in enumerate(gradients):
        self.accu_gradients[i].assign_add(grad)

    # Multiply each gradient with our apply-signal
    final_gradients = [grad * apply for grad in self.accu_gradients]

    self._orig_apply_gradients(zip(final_gradients, trainable_variables), *args, **kwargs)

    # This will reset our buffer whenever "keep" is 0.0
    for g in self.accu_gradients:
        g.assign(g * keep)
```

But the problem is that `self.accu_gradients[i].assign_add(grad)` does not seem to have any effect. And yes, I have also tried

```
self.accu_gradients[i].assign(grad + self.accu_gradients[i])
```

Interestingly, the model starts to converge if I use `assign(grad)` instead as in `self.accu_gradients[i].assign_add(grad)` as you can see:

```
blue: just using assign()   # <- no accumulation happening
red:  using assign_add()
```

[image]

### The `train_step()`

This patch should work model independently. I do have a custom `train_step()` for my model though but the implementation is pretty straight forward.

Here I am just computing the `gradients` and then all the `apply_gradients()` method of the optimizer:

```
def train_step(self, data):

    (inputs, (input_lengths, label_lengths), mask), y_true = data

    loss, gradients = self.rnnt_gradient(
        inputs=inputs,
        y_true=y_true,
        input_lengths=input_lengths,
        label_lengths=label_lengths,
        mask=mask
    )

    self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, self.trainable_variables))

    return {'loss': loss}

def test_step(self, data):

    (inputs, (input_lengths, label_lengths), mask), y_true = data

    val_loss = self.rnnt_loss_wrapper(
        inputs=inputs,
        y_true=y_true,
        input_lengths=input_lengths,
        label_lengths=label_lengths,
        mask=mask
    )

    return dict(loss=val_loss)


def rnnt_gradient(
    self,
    inputs: tuple,
    y_true: tf.Tensor,
    input_lengths: tf.Tensor,
    label_lengths: tf.Tensor,
    mask=None
):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        model_loss = self.rnnt_loss_wrapper(
            inputs,
            y_true=y_true,
            input_lengths=input_lengths,
            label_lengths=label_lengths,
            mask=mask
        )

        is_mixed_precision = isinstance(self.optimizer, mixed_precision.LossScaleOptimizer)

        # We always want to return the unmodified model_loss for Tensorboard
        if is_mixed_precision:
            loss = self.optimizer.get_scaled_loss(model_loss)
        else:
            loss = model_loss

        gradients = tape.gradient(loss, self.trainable_variables)

        if is_mixed_precision:
            gradients = self.optimizer.get_unscaled_gradients(gradients)

        return model_loss, gradients
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gradient Accumulation with Custom model.fit in TF.Keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66472201/gradient-accumulation-with-custom-model-fit-in-tf-keras)

Comment: @M.Innat In essence, it's quite the same what they're doing but I want to implement GA in an optimizer-patch and not on the model-side. The problem I face when using their approach is that `tf.cond` does not work in this context. Idk why this works for them.

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55281501/9215780)?

Comment: @M.Innat Yes, I have seen that too. I have also updated my question to clarify what I have tried and what exactly is not working in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this was totally my fault and it was due to the fact that whenever I trained with a `mixed_float16` policy, I would have patched the *wrong* instance.

What I had was something like:

```py
if precision_policy.name.startswith('mixed'):
    logger.info(f'Using LossScaleOptimizer (policy: "{precision_policy.name})"')
    optimizer = keras.mixed_precision.LossScaleOptimizer(optimizer)

if grad_acc_n > 1:
    # --> This patched the LossScaleOptimizer which caused the problem:
    optimizer = grad_acc.get_patched_optimizer(optimizer=optimizer, n=grad_acc_n)
```

So I would require a check like:

```py
if isinstance(optimizer, keras.mixed_precision.LossScaleOptimizer):
    # Warning: This does NOT work either (just an example)!
    optimizer.inner_optimizer.apply_gradients = accumulator.apply_gradients
    raise Exception('Don\'t do this!')
else:
    optimizer.apply_gradients = accumulator.apply_gradients
```

However, as stated in the comment, patching the `inner_optimizer` does not work either. I haven't figured out why but at least I am now able to run a "normal" `float32`-policy training with my `_GradientAccumulationPatch`-implementation.